# How to Post kendo Grid data source to mvc model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to post kendo Grid data source with mvc model,how can i do that..?
please give any idea..I want to post list of record set with form data and store data in 2 table

id , name , Date  <-- form table
id, FID(Foreign key mapped with form table),Subject, Marks  <-- Record set list I want to add this record from kendo grid

How can I post grid data source with mvc model?
please help me
Regards,
Vinit

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at nesting the grids like in this demo.  You can define separate parent and child update MVC methods.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate

Another option we use is to have a button in the grid that pops up a jquery dialog that gets the child grid html via Ajax.(for the particular row)
If you go this route here are a couple tips:
Append the Ajax html to the body.
Destroy the dialog rather than closing it.
Create the dialog with a  tag inside the tag you use for the dialog.